# Serializing DataTable in C# uses a lot of memory - how to improve this

Tags: c#, mysql, .net, serialization, datatable

**General**
I have something kind of like a proxy for database requests. When sending the result back to the Client the data sent becomes really large - I need to improve this, since otherwise I might run out of memory and the whole application will Crash.

**Here's what I do**
- A client calls the Server
- The server excutes the request and fetches data from a MySql database into `DataTable`
- Next I serialize the `DataTable` via `BinaryFormatter`
- The resulting byte stream is sent back to the client over a TCP-socket

**The Problem**
Now the serialized data which is send (and the memory usage) is really high, especially when it comes to tables with loads of columns and rows that are to be sent. That might add up to a couple hundred of Megabytes.

As I learned, there is a large overhead of XML-Data that is serialized into the data I send over the TCP connection.

**My Question**
Is there a way to reduce the data to be sent, like using a different object that will be serialized, use a different method for serializing the data or anything else that can help to reduce memory usage?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could do a couple of things.

1.) Reduce the size of the datatable by removing any unnecessary columns.

2.) You could try using a different object such as generic `List<T>` since DataTable has lots of information on it.

3.) Change the architecture and not send the entire data back but perform pagination - see https://bytes.com/topic/asp-net/answers/341151-ado-net-sql-server-data-paging on how to perform pagination

Comment: Thanks for your suggestions. I will try suggestion 2) and 3) and let you know about the results. 1) Will only Forward the problem to situations when longer tables are sent.

Comment: 3) Drops out of the options too, since the data needs to be processed later on in whole. I might still try to put the DataTable into another object and serialize that one. We will see if this helps.

Comment: More or less I tried something that avoids the memory issue. I fetch the DataTable but then serialize and send it row by row (or chunks of 20 rows or so). On the client side I reaggregate everything and was able to send the whole DataTable without needing as much memory at one time. That's not exactly your answer but has been inspired by your thought about pagination, so I will accept your answer anyway.

Comment: Thanks - ya the pagination would have been based on your context but well done!